# Cannot access a disposed object C# (showdialog dispose)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to c# and kind of winging it. using Microsoft Visual C# 2010

I have checked many similar posts and none of the suggestions seem to help

I am getting the following error: "Cannot access a disposed object"
which references the main form here

```
private void btn_RunPkgs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunPackages rp = new RunPackages();    
            this.Hide();
            rp.ShowDialog();//The error points to this line
            this.Show();
        }
```

here is the code that blows up when the security check fails.

```
private void securityCheck()
        {
            if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("RUN_JOBS") == 1)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            else
            {
                //this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
                //this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
                MessageBox.Show("You do not have permission to access this form!");
                //this.Close();
                this.Dispose();
            }            
        }
```

**EDIT**
It looks like I am going to go with Adriano Repetti's idea of putting the security where I call the page, but I am a little nervous now having any security on the page.

```
   private void btn_RunPkgs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("RUN_JOBS") == 1)
            {
                RunPackages rp = new RunPackages();
                this.Hide();
                rp.ShowDialog();
                this.Show();                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not for You!");             
            }
        }

        private void btn_ListUpdater_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("MDM") == 1)
            {
                ListUpdater lu = new ListUpdater();

                this.Hide();
                lu.ShowDialog();
                this.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Private!");
            }            
        }
```

**EDIT2**
Came up with the following possible solution but am nervous to use it because I am new at this and don't know what issues there might be. Any problems with just creating an event handler for form load?

```
namespace RunPackages
{
    public partial class ListUpdater : Form
    {
        public ListUpdater()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(securityCheck);
        }    

        private void securityCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("MDM1") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Allowed!");
                this.Close();
            }    
        }
```

Comment: `this.Dispose()` what are you trying to Dispose? Why are you calling that?

Comment: I wrote a security check, if the user fails for that particular form, I want it to display an error message box and close that form, returning to the main form. I first tried this.Clos

Comment: That is because you are `Disposing` of the form during `ShowDialog` so blowing up because it can't reference itself after that point so guessing there is more code you are not showing us.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't need to directly dispose of objects when you're doing most basic coding. Leave that sort of thing to the garbage collector. Why do you have `this.Close()` commented out? Seems like that should be adequate for your needs.

Comment: the security is checked on every form (there are different permissions on different forms) MyGlobals.Formcheck("FormName") checks the user and form permissions. If the permissions are good it works beautifully, it's closing the form when the users fails the check that's a problem.

Comment: this.Close(); was the first thing I tried, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a form has been disposed almost all of its methods can't be accessed (and most of its properties are invalid).

In your first line of `btn_RunPkgs_Click()` you create an object and you dispose it inside its constructor. *Per se*, even if pretty bad habit you *may* even call `Dispose()` from within constructor, it may even work but then you try to use such object `ShowDialog()` will generate `ObjectDisposedException`. Note that this code will also lead to same result (an exception):

```
RunPackages rp = new RunPackages();
rp.Dispose();
```

Yes you *may* check `IsDisposed` but that won't make code readable and problem (IMO) is you're mixing things. Constructor shouldn't contain such logic.

The point isn't just *where* you dispose your form. What's better is to don't even create such form (let me assume, because you call `InitializeComponent()`, that `securityCheck()` is called inside form constructor), for this you may use a factory static method:

```
public static bool TryShowDialog(Form currentForm)
{
    if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("RUN_JOBS") != 1)
        return false;

    if (currentForm != null)
        currentForm.Hide();

    RunPackages dlg = new RunPackages();
    dlg.ShowDialog();   

    if (currentForm != null)
        currentForm.Show();

    return true;
}
```

Your calling function will then be reduced to:

```
private void btn_RunPkgs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunPackages.TryShowDialog(this);
}
```

Note that such function is highly eligible for some refactoring (for example to extract code to hide/show existing form). Something like this:

```
public static bool ShowDialog<T>(Form currentForm, string authorizationId)
    where T : Form, new()
{
    if (MyGlobals.FormCheck(authorizationId) != 1)
        return false;

    if (currentForm != null)
        currentForm.Hide();

    T dlg = new T();
    T.ShowDialog();   

    if (currentForm != null)
        currentForm.Show();

    return true;
}
```

Used like this (now code is reused everywhere):

```
    SecurityHelpers.ShowDialog<RunPackages>(this, "RUN_JOBS");
```

Please note that calling code may be simplified (`authorizationId` may be an attribute on `RunPackages`, for example, and also `currentForm` can be deduced from current active form).

**EDIT** Calling `Close()` isn't better, if window handle has not been created (let's simplify little bit: it's created when window is shown) internally it'll call `Dispose()` (then above applies).

Comment: I use to have the security function in every page, I turned it into a global method/class/thingie (i am new and don't know the terms). I can certainly move the security to the calling page. I will give this a try and let you know. Still not sure why this.Close doesn't work.

Comment: @Lazer Close() doesn't work because...window has not been made visible yet. You're still in constructor (BTW it shouldn't contains any logic but what's needed to create the object itself)

Comment: I am kind of nervous about not having any security on the destination page but this idea works for me. Ended up keeping it far more simple. Thanks for explaining in simple terms why the Close() and Dispose() didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't mean you shouldn't have security checks in your form. It's a good candidate for `Debug.Assert()` and it may even be embedded in a base `AuthorizationRequiredForm` class. Such check is pretty redundant in release but absolutely vital during debugging (and it may be placed in `OnShow` method).

Answer (score 3):

You can't dispose of the form within the form itself. The `ShowDialog()` method tries to access the form on exit for things such as `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to disrupt the chaining of events that lead to the form creation.
The side effects are difficult to predict and what works today could not work in future versions.

Instead I would try a different approach

```
    private void securityCheck()
    {
        if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("RUN_JOBS") == 1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        else
        {
            Label message = new Label();
            message.Dock = DockStile.Fill;
            message.Text("You do not have permission to access this form!.");
            message.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.Controls.Add(message);
        }      
    }
```

In this way I let the form show with just one label that covers the entire form surface with your message. The user could only close the form (provided that you have not removed the Control Box)

By the way, this has the advantage of avoiding dangerous oversights because it doesn't require any change on the calling code and the final effect is to effectively block the use of the form.

If you insist in closing the form during its constructor phase then you could get some advices from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067901/c-sharp-closing-a-form-during-a-constructor)

Comment: +1 Cool solution, but I had some issues with not including InitializeComponent() in the else. Link was useful too, but ended up going with Adriano Repetti's answer

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, can anyone tell me if there are any issues with this?

```
namespace RunPackages
{
    public partial class ListUpdater : Form
    {

        public ListUpdater()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(securityCheck);
        }    

        private void securityCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("MDM1") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not allowed!");
                this.Close();
            }    
        }
```

etc...

Comment: I would merge this into question (or - better - post it on CodeReview as new question) anyway...you don't need to attach an event handler, yo can simply override OnLoad method. Moreover if it's something widely used you may move it to a base class (and well actually, you know, I'd move it completely outside your form but this is another story...)

Answer (score -1):

Use a flag. For example change the code, like this:

```
    public bool IsDisposed;
    private void securityCheck()
            {
                if (MyGlobals.FormCheck("RUN_JOBS") == 1)
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
                else
                {
                    //this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
                    //this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
                    MessageBox.Show("You do not have permission to access this form!");
                    //this.Close();
                    this.Dispose();
                    this.IsDisposed = true;
                }      


        }
```

Then:

```
private void btn_RunPkgs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunPackages rp = new RunPackages();    
            if(rp.IsDisposed)
                return;
            this.Hide();
            rp.ShowDialog();//The error points to this line
            this.Show();
        }
```