# Close window from constructor for a given criteria

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a constructor for my ViewModel given like so:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyViewModel(IMyViewModel view)
        : base(view)
    {
         if (tester.TestConnection(port, ref _errorMessages))
        {
            MethodThatBeginsAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect: " + _errorMessages);
            _abortCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
```

I get an error message of CompositionException when trying to close the corresponding window if the check fails; how can I close the window before it opens?

I.e. the equivalent of:

```
_dialogResult = false;
ViewCore.close();
```

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067901/c-sharp-closing-a-form-during-a-constructor

Comment: No, I'm asking for wpf. That is for winforms

Comment: Why are you manipulating UI elements from your view model? That breaks MVVM.

Comment: @JWiley It is basically the same answer. You need to close it outside of the constructor. You should be doing that logic outside of the constructor if you want to avoid creating it

Answer (score 1):

> "how can I close the window before it opens?"

Don't open it.

You don't have enough context here to provide a better answer than that. What window are you trying to close? What's the message box's parent window? What line throws a CompositionException?

(Note that displaying a messagebox directly from a ViewModel is already a pretty questionable practice, akin (imo) to displaying message boxes from a library that displays no other UI.)