# Prevent the main form from starting up

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

```
public Form1()
{

InitializeComponent();
Update_current_data();  

}

private void Update_current_data()
{
    try
    {
        //...
        //...
        //...
    }
    catch
    {
        switch(MessageBox.Show("You are not connected to a WiFi or your IP address is invalid. The data processes IS UTTER CRAP.",
            "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1))
        {
            case DialogResult.Abort:
                this.Close();
                Application.Exit();
                break;
            case DialogResult.Ignore:
                break;
            case DialogResult.Retry:Update_current_data();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Okay so the `Update_current_data();` is being called even before the form gets loaded and I check if the user is connected to the internet or not at this very time only. Now if the user is not connected an exception is thrown and a MessageBox is displayed asking the user to `Abort`, `ignore` or `Retry`. (The form is yet to load)

Now here is the problem. If the user clicks on `abort` I want the form to never load and the application shut down completely. But I cant use `this.Close();` as an exception again occurs in `Program.cs` saying:

> 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Form1'.'

and `Application.Exit();` has no effect on it as the Form opens up regardless.

So how can I prevent the form from showing up here itself. Also I don't want to handle the exception thrown by `this.Close();` in `Program.cs.

Comment: Why don't you move the code that checks the internet in your main method (Program.cs) before starting the main form?

Comment: @Steve I got both your comments but I want to learn how to prevent the form from opening from the Form class itself. And yes `form1` is my main form.

Comment: Then this QA could be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067901/c-sharp-closing-a-form-during-a-constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. Both that answer as well as Reza's answer work.

Comment: However that answer will not help you if you don't want to close your whole app.

Comment: Although I have my answer and there is a workaround Ill follow the better practise to include it in Program.cs itself. I do want to close my whole app. The whole question was about learning a new way. I could just call the update function under `Form_load` and skip all the hassle but I want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the form to never load and the application shut down
>   completely.

Since you are going to shut down the application, you can use [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It terminates the process and returns an exit code to the OS. For example:

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

**Note:** **In general It's better to check for the criteria before trying to show the form.** But since you are looking for a way to exit the application, you should know it's completely possible to exit the application using `Environment.Exit` method event in form's constructor. But if you are looking for just closing the form in constructor, you can not do it in constructor, you should subscribe for `Load` event of the form and close the form there. To see an example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564143/3110834).

Comment: Would you mind explaining me why `Application.exit()` doesn't work?

Comment: Probably because of the same reason that `Form.Close` doesn't work. `Application.Exit` in fact tries to close all forms gently.

Comment: `Form.Close` throws an exception but `Application.Exit` behaves like nothing ever happened...

Comment: [`Application.Exit`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,de3600ec6a11dcac,references) hides the exceptions internally.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are doing your check it is already too late, because you are already inside your form.
For this to work, you need to move your check to the Program.cs before it creates the new Form1();

Then you can properly abort the creation of the window before it actually occurs.

Comment: No I am definitely not in my form when the check is going on. And the exception is thrown because I tried to close my form before it even started. My question is how can I prevent my form from opening up, this clearly implies that my form has not yet loaded till the `MessageBox` is discplayed or else the function `Form1_Load()` would already have been called.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) is the order in which the form loads.

Comment: @Rishav could you explain? The Form1 is not your main form? The one started by Application.Run in your program.cs file? Me (in my comment) and this answer are telling you to move this code before the call to Application.Run. If the code fails there is no form to close because no form has been opened

Comment: @Rishav, you are calling your Update_current_data function from your Form1() constructor. So you are clearly inside your form already. You should check where you Form1() constructor is called from and put your check code before that even happens.

Comment: Yeah I got that but I want to learn how can i prevent the form from opening from the Form class itself. And yes `form1` is my main form.

Comment: @Rishav you cannot do that from the Form itself. The only thing you can do is forcefully close it after your check. A better practice would be to not open the form at all unless the check says it's ok to do so. And that you can only do it before you even call your Form1 constructor.

Comment: @PicMickael Ya I am inside the form but the form has not yet loaded. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms